# Proving $3^n \geq 3n$ using mathematical induction

Tags: induction

So I have to prove that $3^n$ is greater than or equal to $3n$ using induction. The base case is a not a problem, but I can't seem to figure out where to go for $(n-1)$. I've tried saying:
$$3^n=3\cdot3^{n-1}>3\cdot3(n-1)$$
$$3\cdot3(n-1)=9n-9$$

I'm pretty sure my end goal is $3n$, but I'm not really sure how to get there.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, just note $9n-9\ge 3n$ as soon as $n>1$.

Comment: Why are you trying to prove $n-1$? Shouldn't it be for $n+1$?

Comment: The math book I'm using teaches n-1. I know that's not a great answer, but it is what it is.

Comment: Well one is a **product** of 3's, the other is a **sum** of 3's. Just note that for any positive integers, $a, b$, greater than 1,  $ab \gt a+b$.

Comment: I'd love to, however I'm not smart enough to figure out how changing it from n-1 to n+1 would change the proof. I also have to assume that n is greater than or equal to two, so I would think that that would also change.

Comment: PJ: I suspect what is happening is the following: your book says that (after doing the base case) if you assume it to be true for $n-1$, and you then prove it for $n$, then you say 'Induction!' and are done. If this is true, you should *not* be manipulating the $n-1$ case. Rather, you should start with the $n$ case, and manipulate it until it looks like $n-1$ case (possibly with some extras hanging around.)

Comment: Making the change of variables $m=n-1$, you can also assume the $m$ case, and prove the $m+1$ case. (In other words, *start* with the $m+1$ case, and make it look like the $m$ case). This is what most books do, but as you can see, they are equivalent because you're just making an easy substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show that we may assume that the inequality holds for some $k$ and use that to show that it holds for $k+1$.

Use the base case $n=2$, $3^2>3(2)$, which is obviously true.

Now, assume that for $n=k$ that $3^k>3k$. This is called the induction hypothesis. Now, we must prove the inequality for $k+1$.

$3^k>3k$ via our induction hypothesis.

$3\cdot3^k>3\cdot3k$ multiplying by $3$ on both sides.

$3^{k+1}>3\cdot3k>3k+3=3(k+1)$

Thus, the inductive step and our proof are complete.

Comment: Hello, I have a doubt with regards to your answer. I do not understand the following step: $3k+1>3⋅3k>3k+3$. How did you get $3k+3$? Cheers!!

Comment: I got it. It's because if 3k + 1 is greater than 3*3k then it is certainly greater 3k + 3. eg. 3*3(2) > 3*2  + 3 => 18 > 9: Hence true.

Answer (score 1):

Prove (again by induction) that 9(n-1) is larger or equal than 3n for n larger or equal than 2.